# How can I use lambdify to evaluate my function?

Tags: python, numpy, symbols, sympy, lambdify

I have an expression with several variables, let's say something like below:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
from sympy import Symbol, Add, re, lambdify
x = sym.Symbol('x')
y = sym.Symbol('y')
z = sym.Symbol('z')

F = x+ y +z
```

I have three lists for the variables like below:

```
x = [3, 2 ,3]   
y = [4, 5 , 6] 
z = [7, 10 ,3]
```

I want to evaluate my function for the each element of my variables.
I know I can define something like below:

```
f_dis = lambdify([x, y, z], x + y + z, 'numpy')
d = f_dis(3, 4, 7)
print ( "f_dis =", d)
```

which give me 14 as the desired result. But how can I pass the x, y, and z as three lists (instead of writing the elements separately) and get a result like below:

```
[14, 17, 12]
```

It seems using lambdify is a more efficient way to evaluate a function, based on this note:
https://www.sympy.org/scipy-2017-codegen-tutorial/notebooks/22-lambdify.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')
y = sp.Symbol('y')
z = sp.Symbol('z')

X = [3, 2 ,3]   
Y = [4, 5 , 6] 
Z = [7, 10 ,3]

values = list(zip(X, Y, Z))


f_dis = sp.lambdify([x, y, z], x + y + z, 'numpy')
ans = [f_dis(*value) for value in values]
for d in ans:
    print ( "f_dis =", d)
```

this will give you:

```
f_dis = 14
f_dis = 17
f_dis = 12
```